# How to fix "static assertion failed: template argument not an integral type" error?

Tags: c++, random, numbers

I want to generate any number between 0 and max value of given type(T). There is no problem with generating numbers for int, short, long, etc, but i cannot do this for float and double. I get this error: "static assertion failed: template argument not an integral type".
My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <random>

template<class T>
T questGenerator()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::default_random_engine generator(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<T> distribution(0, std::numeric_limits<T>::max());

    return distribution(generator);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << questGenerator<float>();
}
```

This is an input and output example that I was given:
 input:

```
std::cout << generateQuest<short>() << std::endl;
std::cout << generateQuest<short>() << std::endl;
std::cout << (short)generateQuest<char>() << std::endl;
std::cout << (short)generateQuest<char>() << std::endl;
std::cout << generateQuest<float>() << std::endl;
std::cout << generateQuest<float>() << std::endl;
```

output:

```
10105
5332
52
110
3.39889e+38
2.7026e+38
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is *undefined behaviour* to use `std::uniform_int_distribution<T>` for any `T` different than: `short`, `int`, `long`, `long long`, `unsigned short`, `unsigned int`, `unsigned long`, or `unsigned long long`.

You might want to consider [`std::uniform_real_distribution<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution).

Additionally, it's generally a bad idea to have multiple *generators* per thread. You'd be better of sticking to using a reference to a single one.